Moving laser beam passing over stationary circular opening
I am in need of help with the following situation. I appreciate any insight. Imagine a circular laser beam of diameter d1 moving at velocity v passing over a stationary circular opening of diameter d2 so the full diameter of d1 passes over the full diameter of d2 along the same plane.  The magnitudes of d1 and d2 are within an order of magnitude. My goal is to determine how much energy is transferred through the stationay circular opening of diameter d2 as the light of diameter d1 passes over the stationay opening at a velocity v. I´m stuck with one circle passing over another circle(assuming they pass along their diameters) at a certain speed to calculate the "amount of area" they overlapped in the time taken for the beam to pass over the opening (to then use that area to the easily calculate the energy transferred through).  I want to see the math to determine the impact of varying v, d1 OR d2 on the energy transferred through the opening.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Welcomne// Where is your problem ? Need you help to compute the area of intersection of  the two discs ?  Or something else ?

A good place to start is Gaussian Beams. The focal spot of a laser is not a circular disk of uniform intensity. It has a central bright spot that fades away as you get farther from the center. There really is no edge. The beam diameter is the diameter where the intensity is $13$% of the central intensity. The intensity drops to ~$1$% at $1.5$ times the diameter. This is close enough to $0$ for most purposes.

Laser beams tend to be closer to Gaussian rather than "constant intensity circular".

I think what you are looking for is called a convolution, which is an integral transform of the form: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$
It has been a while since I've had to compute one of these, but here is a link to a similar question being asked in math stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990716/2d-convolution-of-two-circles
However, I can tell you that the outcome will be a Gaussian. The trick is that the convolution of a Gaussian is a Gaussian. The laser has a Gaussian power distribution, and the aperture is a square function (you can reduce this problem to 1D). The outcome will be a Gaussian, assuming the aperture is not diffracting the beam.
I want to add that perhaps a more straightforward picture is that of the knife-edge measurement commonly done in laser experiments. You take a knife which is initially blocking a laser beam. You step the knife out of the way of the beam using a micrometer and measure power as a function of knife position. If the beam diameter was infinitely small (Dirac delta beam profile), you would get a super sharp step function. Now, the derivative of the Heaviside step function is a dirac delta. So, for a beam with a finite diameter (gaussian profile), you will observe a smoothed-out step function, the derivative of which is a Gaussian, the FWHM of which is the beam diameter.

This might help - But what is a convolution?
